# Kubernetes through Virtualbox; Pods can't access internet services

Tags: domain-name-system, firewall, kubernetes, nslookup, resolv.conf

System:
VirtualBox, Debian 10 Server, Kubernetes with kubeadm

I've setup a deployment and a service and I am exposing it via NodePort but my Pods somehow cant access the internet. The worker node which runs the pod however has an internet connection. I tested this by exec into the running pod and curl a webpage.

**Pods**

```
root@master:/home/user# kubectl get pods
NAME                               READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
my-website-6d8f7c7bfb-sdtrh        1/1     Running     1          6d1h
```

**Curl from Host**

```
root@master:/home/user# curl https://wikipedia.org
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://www.wikipedia.org/">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

**Exec Pod - Curl**

```
root@master:/home/user# kubectl exec -it my-website-6d8f7c7bfb-sdtrh /bin/bash
root@my-website-6d8f7c7bfb-sdtrh:/sbin# curl https://wikipedia.org
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: wikipedia.org
```

Anyone an idea what that could be? I'm fairly new to DevOps, so I don't know quite as much about all of that yet.

**EDIT for Howard_Roark**

1. I've checked and yes the two `/etc/resolv.conf`'s differ.

**On worker node**

```
root@worker:~# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Generated by NetworkManager
search fritz.box
nameserver 192.168.178.1
```

**Inside Pod**

```
/ # cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local fritz.box
options ndots:5
```

2. From the node itself I can get out to another name server, but not from the pod.

```
root@worker:~# nslookup wikipedia.org 8.8.8.8
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   wikipedia.org
Address: 91.198.174.192
Name:   wikipedia.org
Address: 2620:0:862:ed1a::1


root@worker:~# nslookup wikipedia.org 1.1.1.1
Server:     1.1.1.1
Address:    1.1.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   wikipedia.org
Address: 91.198.174.192
Name:   wikipedia.org
Address: 2620:0:862:ed1a::1
```

3. Is presumable gonna fail too hence 2. But I'll test it now.

Comment: Did you try restarting CoreDNS pod?

Comment: Are you using any network policies?

Comment: No network policies so far, do I need them?

Comment: No, but if you had, configured incorrectly could block dns queries.

Comment: Does this happen only in this one container or every container?

Comment: Happens on every container

Comment: I am using calico networking but I dont think it introduces any network policies

Comment: kubectl get networkpolicies
No resources found in default namespace.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115087/discussion-between-jayson-and-matt).

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

The Problem disappeared after I moved to a proper development server. Apparently the Kubernetes cluster does not properly run with bridged AirPort network environments in Virutalbox.

Comment: Great that you were able to solve it, but please don't add `Solved` to the title of your question. Accept your answer when you can (usually after 2 days) and your question will be marked as solved by the system.

Comment: Thanks Gerald. I've updated it.